# Ask a few questions about the following sentence

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, grammar

> ‘He stares soulfully past the camera, ***on*** toward a catering truck where
>   sushi rolls and ham sandwiches dwell side by side in harmony.’

what's the usage of ***on*** in the sentence? pls help me with the analysis of the whole sentence.

Comment: Where does this come from? Source please!

Comment: @SovereignSun https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/roll

Comment: **"He stares [soulfully past the camera], on toward..."** maybe this'll help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we break it down into the main words, we get:

> He stares past the camera on toward a truck.

In this case, "on towards a truck" is adding detail. The description is following the line of sight of the person: Past the camera, and *on towards* the truck. In this case the word "on" implies a continuation of the gaze: It is continuing to go forward, to the truck.

"He stares on" can have a couple of other meanings, depending on the context:

- "He stares on." = He continues to stare.
- "He stares on (object)" = He is focused on that object.